# Better approach to hide and show

Tags: jquery

I currently have a couple of tables, and also forms, so I'm using this to display them:

```
switch (table) {

    case "table1":
        $("#form1").show();
        $("#form2").hide();
    break;

   case "table2":
        $("#form1").hide();
        $("#form2").show();
    break;
}
```

So if I have 1000 buttons, imagine repeating all that..., is there a better approach to not repeat all that code again and again?

Comment: Is there a rule?  eg table1->show form1, hide all the others?  ie `$("form").hide();$("form1").show();` would be a start.  The next step would be to link the table1 and form1 using data-attributes, but that depends on any rules.

Comment: @freedomn-m hi, not rule, simply if table is chosen, display the correct form, how would I do it?

Comment: the rule would define the "correct form" - put another way, when you select a table, how does it know which form to use?  Also what's "table"?

Comment: @freedomn-m because the form has an id `<form id="form1">`, so right now I'm copy pasting all those forms in all the tables, repeating the same code

Comment: So on the code, I'm writing every form, if you look at the original post, it says on table1, write both forms but display only 1, so it only shows 1. Requirements: When a user selects 1 table from the drop down, show a specific form called by the id

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense to you, but it's not specific enough / too vague.  How does "table1" match "form1"?  While it's obvious that they both end in 1, is that the rule?  "tableX" matches "formX"?  Or can they be arbitrary?  Do you want a solution that parses the ID for "1" or something more robust?   Is "table1" an html element? A `<select>` option? (ie something you can add "data-" to).  Are they all `<form>` tags or something else?  If something else, can you add `class='form'` to all of them so they can be found easily, rather than the not-very-nice `$("[id^=form]").hide()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would structure my code in a way allows to use less code like in the following snippet here I'm only passing input radio value and use it to construct my `<form>` id attribute and use it to only show the table in question.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('form').toggle();
  $("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
     $('form').hide();
    $('#form' + $(this).val()).toggle();
  })
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="radio"  name="form" value="1">
<label for="form1">form1</label>

<input type="radio" name="form" value="2">
<label for="form2">form2</label>

<input type="radio"  name="form" value="3">
<label for="form3">form3</label>

<input type="radio" name="form" value="4">
<label for="form4">form4</label>


<form id="form1">
  <lable>input form 1</lable>
  <input type="text" />
</form>
<form id="form2">
  <lable>input form 2</lable>
  <input type="text" />
</form>
<form id="form3">
  <lable>input form 3</lable>
  <input type="text" />
</form>
<form id="form4">
  <lable>input form 4</lable>
  <input type="text" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a selector to hide all forms, then show the one you need to show using an ID.